# Convert a text file into ARFF file

Tags: weka, arff

I am trying to convert a text file into an ARFF (Attribute Relation File Format) file. Below are the first few lines of the file.

```
@RELATION Graph

@ATTRIBUTE real {1,-1}
@ATTRIBUTE authorOne string
@ATTRIBUTE authorTwo string
@ATTRIBUTE year real

@DATA
1,authorName1,authorName2,1999
    ....
```

I am getting the below error on loading this file onto weka.

train.arff is not recognized as an 'Arff data files' file.
Reason: number expected, read token[authorName1]

Could you please let me know what's wrong with this?

Comment: @ATTRIBUTE real {1,-1}
do you try to define the class label here?

Comment: yes this is the class label.

Comment: in this case you should change the "real" into "class" or something else. Have you checked this: https://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+(stable+version)